# How to write a method header that throws exception

Tags: java, exception, methods, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

"Given that FileInputStream’s constructor throws FileNotFoundException, which is a subclass of
Exception, write the header for a public method named process that takes a String parameter
and returns nothing, and whose body instantiates a FileInputStream object and does not contain
a try-catch statement."

I know it's a too-simple question but I want to make sure I'm not messing up in a dumb way.  Also, not sure whether to use FileNotFoundException or just Exception or IO, etc.

```
public process(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("stuff.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have for the throws clause is good. Throwing IOException would not be terrible, but it's better to be specific. Calling code can still treat it as an IOException.

Generally you shouldn't throw Exception except for special cases (Junit methods and similar situations where everything thrown will get caught by an exception handler), because it forces everything that calls it into the position of either handling Exception (where it may not be the appropriate place to do it, it is better to let most exceptions bubble up to one place where they can get handled uniformly) or also throwing Exception, which then puts other calling methods in the same position.

Your method declaration is not valid because there's no return type. Methods that don't return anything are declared with a return type of void.

Using the same name for a method parameter as for a local variable will not work, you should make those different. The constructor call should take the method parameter as an argument (instead of hard-coding a string literal). (+1 to [geceo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900359/217324) for pointing that one out, I had missed that one.)

As a suggestion, your code would be clearer if it used names that reflected the contents of the variables. Calling a FileInputStream `file` is not clear, it would be better to call it `inputStream`. Calling a String `file` is not clear, it would be better to call it `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine (except you're missing the `void` return type).

Always throw (and catch) the narrowest specification of `Exception` you can (in this case `FileNotFoundException`).

Answer (score 1):

As spotted by Nathan, you forgot to declare that `process` returns nothing, that is, you forgot the `void` keyword.

There's another problem with your parameter `String file` ("duplicate local variable *file*"). You should rename it `String filename` and pass it to the constructor of `FileInputStream`:

```java
public void process(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
}
```

About the general topic, you always have to make a choice when you call a method that throws exception(s):

- You can use a try/catch block and deal with the error in your calling method (log them, for example);

*or*

- You can propagate the exception using the `throws` keyword in your method declaration.

So what you're doing here is the second possibility.

Comment: good catch, i missed the part about the method argument and local variable names.

Comment: And I missed the "void". :)

Answer (score 0):

Also add `void` as the return type.  **Rest is fine.**

```
public void process(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("stuff.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do few things to make your method better by buying insurance against accidental misuse:

```
public void process(final String file) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("stuff.txt");
    //invoke operations on inputStream object
    //After 100 lines of code
    inputStream = new FileInputStream("foo.txt"); // compile error
}
```

Observe the final keyword next to parameter passed to method and FileInputStream object reference.